# Windows 10, 11, 2019, 2022 Resource Monitor DPI settings

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-11, dpi, resource-monitor

After Windows 7/2008 i found, that new Windows on 4k monitors with 150% fonts scale makes old Windows app blurry, for most i found solution via '~ HIGHDPIAWARE' registry option (mmc.exe and all child works fine). But Resource Monitor (for some reason resmon.exe launch perfmon.exe) left without changes and blurred fonts. I add registry keys for both exes files. Added global var __COMPAT_LAYER=HighDpiAware, no effect.

Is it possible to make DPI normal for this app? Manifest file, startup command line options?

P.S. problem solved via files permissions (i set to all involved also to system32 admin full control, yep, maybe not so secure, but is working)

Comment: For me 4k monitors with 150% work fine. Perhaps you should undo all your registry fixes. I don't think that you need them in Windows 11.

Comment: @harrymc 'work fine' is very subjective opinion :), can you post screenshot with Resource Monitor and Notepad (on example) for comparison....?

Comment: Will this example do : https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8lqp.jpg

Comment: only Notepad, but what about Resource monitor?

Comment: Resource monitor is also not blurry. In fact, no application I ever use on Windows 10 or in a Windows 11 VM was ever blurry or required registry modifications. I have to assume that your modifications have created a problem worse than the one you originally tried to solve.

Comment: @harrymc
https://www.mediafire.com/view/xzg7ip2uln3rgtb/sharp_text.png/file
sharp text example - what i want to achieve
but you need download this file locally, because for some reason via browser it looks different

Comment: I also have the exact same issue (I'm using 1440p with 125% scaling), I managed to modify all other programs like perfmon and event viewer in the registry by changing the DPI aware settings and they are all sharp.  
Only one is resource monitor which ignores the setting.